# How to avoid browser sync causing server error

Tags: javascript, gulp, browser-sync, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I am using gulp browser sync in the web app I have developed using Microsoft Visual Studio. The issue has occured when I started using browser sync to reload the page whenever a file has been modified. My app is running on my default [localhost](http://localhost:64510/). The development build succeeds but it can't open the site. The following is my gulp code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var bs = require('browser-sync').create();
gulp.task('serve', [], function() {
  // .init starts the server
  bs.init({
    server: "./",
    port: 64510
  });
});
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('scss/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
    .pipe(bs.reload({ stream: true }));
});
gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync'], function() {
  gulp.watch("scss/*.scss", ['sass']);
  gulp.watch("*.html").on('change', bs.reload);
});
gulp.task('build', ['clean-code', 'serve', 'browser-sync'], function() {});
```

[image: screenshot]
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You call a 'browser-sync' task twice in your provided code but there is no actual 'browser-sync' task.  For example, your 'build' has such a call:

```
gulp.task('build', ['clean-code', 'serve', 'browser-sync'], function() {});
```

and so does the 'watch' task:

```
gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync'], function() {
```

Get rid of those two 'browser-sync' references and it will work.